# Smallest digital 3-axis gyroscope pcb for arduino?

Tags: gyroscope

What is the smallest size digital 3-axis gyroscope pcb compatible with an arduino that I can buy or maybe make if its simple enough. I need one really really tiny probably around 0.8x0.1x0.5 (doesn't have to be that small but the smaller the better).

Thanks,

Comment: How small you can make depends on your skills - what are they? You may find trouble finding a fab house that is willing to make such small boards - commonly 10mm² is a minimum size.

Comment: The recent invensense parts come in 3x3 mm QFN packages, you could probably put them on a 6mm x 6mm PCB - really the challenge would be getting the wires for the offboard connections to them.  If you want really small, put a QFN ATmega on the reverse side as your "Arduino" and make the board no bigger than that requires.  OSHPark should be able to make the board for you for around $1 each, and you can build it with solder paste and a $60 hot air station.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

smallest board is no board.  pick a small BGA or LGA shaped accelerometer and superglue it face down to the arduino board then solder fine wires beween the chip terminals and arduino terminals.

search digikey for 'spi accelerometer'

Comment: That technique is known as Dead Bug.

Comment: @Jasen I meant gyro but I get what you mean. I found an example of a LGA shaped gyro here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/GYROSCOPE-3AXIS-2000DPS-L3GD20-STMICROELECTRONICS/dp/B018COVMAM/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1457819243&sr=8-14&keywords=LGA+gyroscope How big would that chip be?

Comment: Of course that ends up as big as the arduino - which by extension means you could do the same thing with substantially easier soldering by using a typical SMT part as sold on a breakout board (which is incidentally often cheaper than buying a single bare chip anyway)

Comment: @ChrisStratton  Yh of course but couldn't I solder some 0.35mm^2 wires to the IC chip so that I can mount it wherever I want and have an Arduino somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Arduino accesories are generally large because they are meant to be easy to use. mpu-6050 is a good example and you can find many decent breakout boards for it. But if you really want it to be very small, you should consider a custom solution for your problem like designing a PCB that holds both the microcontroller and the accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

Bosch CNO055 chip is an IMU-Cortex combo capable of outputting 3-D coordinates directly in several formats via several data interfaces. Adafruit has a product based on this chip, along with Arduino library (the CNO055 is in the middle to get you an idea about minimum size) -> https://www.adafruit.com/products/2472.